# c# String filtering and split with regex match

Tags: c#, regex, string, if-statement, filtering

I'm trying to to filter strings with regex but i'm not that familiar with regex so i need a little help. Also i need to check if string contains specific regex part like example of input bellow:

**Input (string):**

```
"<value1;127.0.0.1:20000;value2;value3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!"
```

**If exist return these values:**

```
string val1 = ????; //can't be null or empty, must be at least 3 chars/ints
string val2 = ????; //can be empty string
string val3 = ????; //can be empty string
string ipaddress = ????; // can't be empty
string text = ????; //can be empty string
```

**Otherwise if not exist return only "lorem ipsum..." text:**

```
string text = ????; //can be empty string
```

So first i need to check if that specific part  exist in full string.
String can be without that part.

Can please someone explain me how I can do that?

**EDIT:** *(please don't judge, i'm really bad with regex)*
Here is what i tried:

```
private static bool ifContain(string a)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(a, @"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\;([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{5})([a-zA-Z0-9*)\;([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\;([<a-zA-Z0-9]*)");
}
```

Comment: Google regex rules and regex debugger (then read and experiment) if you cant solve it, come back and show us your regex and string.

Comment: Quick comment, you can use this function: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` or `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check if it's empty.

Comment: Okay, i edited post, i post my poor example.

Comment: Here is your regex capturing all the parts: [`^<(?<val1>[a-zA-Z0-9]*);(?<val2>[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}:[0-9]{5});(?<val4>[a-zA-Z0-9]*);(?<val5>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)>(?<val6>.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/dZ2mE8/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way combining regex and split. I did not do any null/empty/whitespace validation, nor did I validate that the `split` results contain at least 4 elements. This uses capture groups to select text from within the match, and it just blindly grabs all text it can in the groups using `.*`, where the groups are defined with the parenthesis.

```
        string txt = "<value1;127.0.0.1:20000;value2;value3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!";
        var rgx = new Regex(@"<(.*)>(.*)");
        var match = rgx.Match(txt);
        // Should check if (match.Success) here and only continue if true
        var entireMatch = match.Groups[0]; // unused
        var firstCaptureGroup = match.Groups[1].Value; // Everything between < >
        var secondCaptureGroup = match.Groups[2].Value; // Everything after < >
        var split = firstCaptureGroup.Split(';');

        string val1 = split[0]; 
        string val2 = split[2]; 
        string val3 = split[3]; 
        string ipaddress = split[1]; 
        string text = secondCaptureGroup;
```

Comment: Since my ifContain method works now (didn't work before for some reason) this is what i'm searching for to split. Thank you.

Comment: Ok just see my minor edit, there's lots of validation to do and one of them is checking the `match.Success` property because if it's false then there's no reason to try and continue.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly way `without` Regex:

```
var str = "<value1;127.0.0.1:20000;value2;value3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!";

var split = str.Split(';'); 
var split2 = split[3].Split('>');

var val1 = split[0].Split('<')[1];
var ip = split[1];
var val2 = split[2];    
var val3 = split2[0];
var text = split2[1];
```

if any of these values for some reason don't exist, you can check afterwards using  the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` function

So, for instance:

```
var str = "<;;;>";

var split = str.Split(';');

var val1 = split[0].Split('<')[1];

Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val1)); //true
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know how to split that but i was thinking is there maybe some different way to do that using regex because these strings will contain sometime that specific part so i need to check if that part exists, if exists then split it.